# What is the difference between "Skip" and "Continue" in an alert?

Tags: gui-design

[image]

When I try to delete a file which is in use, the alert gives me 3 options: "Skip", "Stop", "Continue".

I know `"Stop"` means to cancel this action.

But `"Skip"` and `"Continue"` seems to have the same result that is the file has not been deleted.

What is the difference between `"Skip"` and `"Continue"` in an alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you are deleting entire folder containing 3 (just random) files. Let us name them `file-1`, `file-2`, `file-3`.

Now consider `file-1` is in use, so system could not permit your request to delete that file, while remaining files(`file-2` & `file-3`) are not being used currently.

So in this case when the process of deleting entire folder starts it will try to delete `file-1` but since it's in use it will ask you these options.

Now

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQOuuL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**UPDATE: Your Case**

In your case there might be just `one-file`, so when you click `Continue`, it would try to terminate the process using it and delete. But wouldn't be able to terminate the process using it(that file). So you can not be able to delete it **(Alike Skip)**.

Answer (score 0):

**Continue** means to keep retrying, this might run the risk of the current operation being a blocker for the remaining operations in the queue.

**Skip** means to skip this operation and proceed to the next task in the queue.